# Ingesting data from Kinesis Streams using Apache Flink (AWS KDA)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am getting this error while reading data from Kinesis Streams (4 shards) with Flink. Apparently by default, Flink subscribes itself to topic every 5mins and I set parallelism to 3. I also checked this metric *Read throughput exceeded - average (Percent)* for the Kinesis Stream but seems normal to me. Any clues about it?

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Maximum retries exceeded for SubscribeToShard. Failed 10 times. at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.fanout.FanOutRecordPublisher.runWithBackoff at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(Object, ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)`

I have been searching on Web for topics that mention this error. No luck so far.

Comment: Aren't there any more logs suggesting what went wrong? `ChannelClosedException` means that the channel has been closed for some reason, so there should be some info regarding why this happened.

Comment: Hey were you able to identify the root cause and fix of this ??